# Proving the following group inequality.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $(G,*)$ be a group and $H,K ≤ G .$ How can I prove that $[G:K] ≥ [H:H∩K]$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$|G|\geq|HK|=\frac{|H|\cdot|K|}{|H\cap K|} = |K|\cdot|H:H\cap K|.$$
 So,
$$
|G:K| = \frac{|G|}{|K|}\geq |H: H\cap K|,
$$
with equality iff $$HK=G.$$

Comment: This argument does not work if $G$ is infinite and $|G:K|$ is finite.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you, I thought that $G$ is finite.

Comment: For the case, when $G$ is infinite, we can do as follows. Let $\rho$ be the equivalence relation on $G$ such that $g_1\rho g_2$ iff $g_1g^{-1}_2\in K$, then the number of equivalence classes is finite and equal to the $|G:K|$. We can restrict this relation on $H$ and get new relation $\rho' = \rho|_H$. Then the number of equivalence classes is not greater than $|G:K|$ and equals to $|H:H\cap K|$.